# Ruby 3.0.4 with Postgres 14 throws segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6.1, ruby-3

I have

```
Ruby 3.0.4
Rails 6.1.7
pg 1.4.5
postgresql 14.6
```

Here is my database.yml file

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: utf8
database: olio_development
username: postgres
password: password
pool: 5 
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 5432
gssencmode: disable
```

When I run rake db:create I am getting the following segmentatin fault

```
/home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/pg-1.4.5/lib/pg/connection.rb:626: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00007fd79729a140
```

ruby 3.0.4p208 (2022-04-12 revision 3fa771dded) [x86_64-linux]

```
-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
 c:0050 p:---- s:0275 e:000274 CFUNC  :connect_poll
c:0049 p:0543 s:0271 e:000270 METHOD /home/suganya/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/pg-1.4.5/lib/pg/connection.rb:626
```

The connection fails.

I have verified postgres is running and is on host 127.0.0.1 and post 5432.

Please help me how to resolve this segmentation fault?

Comment: Has this code worked previously? What changed between it working and it not working? Rails or pg gems updated (even a tiny version bump)? Postgres updated?  Ruby updated? Does it work on one machine but not another?

Comment: @iftheshoefritz This is a fresh project which has been started directly on the above mentioned versions.

Comment: No, the issue is still there.

Comment: @SuganyaSelvarajan how far back did you test? Unscientifically, `1.3.2` would be worth a shot.

Answer (score 24):

I came across this question while searching for a solution to a similar issue. So will post the fix which worked for me, maybe it will help someone else.

My environment:

```
Ruby 3.2.2
Rails 7.0.4.3
pg 1.4.5
postgresql 14.9
```

Adding the following line to `.zshrc` (and restarting the terminal) fixed the problem for me:

```bash
export PGGSSENCMODE="disable"
```

This [Github Issue comment](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/311#issuecomment-1609970533) provides more background about the root cause and why you're seeing it. It includes a few possible resolutions, including the one above:

> - Disable GSSAPI via the `PGGSSENCMODE=disable` environment variable or pass `gssencmode=disable` in the connection string.
> - Initiate the database connection by preloading the app before forking so the macOS system calls are invoked in the parent process.
>   In Puma, the `preload_app!` config option does this.
> - Use a PostgreSQL server that does not have `--with-gssapi` enabled. By default I believe the Homebrew version has this, but asdf does not
>   install PostgreSQL with this. You can check by using `otool -L`.

Comment: It also fixed for:

Ruby 3.1.2
Rails 7.0.6
pg 1.4.2
PostgreSQL 14.9
MacOS 13.5.1 (22G90)

Comment: Oh man, thanks for this! I have been dealing with this for the last four days. I tried everything. It turned out to be this flag :)

Comment: I'm running Ruby 3.0.4 and 3.1.2 with Postgres@11 on an M1 Macbook Pro (Ventura) and this fix worked for me. I encountered my issue after a Homebrew upgrade with no Ruby changes. Thank you!

Comment: > Initiate the database connection by preloading the app before forking so the macOS system calls are invoked in the parent process. In Puma, the preload_app! config option does this.

This doesn't work for me, but you're absolutely right that it should. Setting `gssencmode: disable` in `database.yml` does work, but feels very heavy handed. I'm left wondering why the `preload_app!` approach isn't working.

Is anyone else seeing this?

Ruby: `3.0.6`
pg: `1.5.4`
Rails: `6.1.7.4`

Comment: worked to me. thank you! rails 7 and ruby 3.1.2

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** the segfault described in the original question was caused by the PG client libraries, not the pg gem, so this answer doesn’t help with it. See the above answer instead. However, pinning older versions of a gem is always a reasonable troubleshooting step when you start to suddenly see failures you can’t otherwise debug in a process known as [bisecting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_(software_engineering).

I'm seeing a GitHub issue for the pg gem (https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/493) that matches your problem, so it might be a bug with pg v1.4.5. I would try pinning it to an older version:

```
gem 'pg', '1.4.4'
```

And work your way backwards if that still has issues. You can also add your information to the GitHub issue linked above to help the maintainers resolve the issue.

Comment: @Nello I posted this eight months before that answer in the hopes of iterating back-and-forth with the OP to produce an actual answer. Unfortunately, they stopped responding. Glad to see the root cause has been found! I did a little more research and updated the above answer with additional details, too.

Comment: I know you were trying to help, but your answer is wrong and you didn't check it. That path does not lead to the solution. You should remove it.

Comment: @Nello I couldn’t reproduce it, so obviously I couldn’t check it. And no one who could repro it responded to me. Until ten months later, when you showed up and decided to pointlessly shame me. This answer was wrong for this segfault, but in a few years it might actually help someone with a different segfault that *was* part of the native extensions for this gem or another one. Meanwhile, the other answer has more upvotes and should be accepted. That’s how StackOverflow works.